# Azure Pipelines Automatic retries for a task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

This is part of my Yml file
I need to re-call this template if it failed.it should be rerun again. After a few seconds, ideally.I am new to yml files
I tried to use retryCountOnTaskFailure but it should be under task but the template calling different hierarchy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-195-update#automatic-retries-for-a-task

```
- template: ${{variables['System.DefaultWorkingDirectory']}}
    parameters:
      Test: ${{ parameters.isTestRelease }}
      Environment: ${{ parameters.deploymentTarget }}
      Component: '${{ parameters.component }}'
```

Comment: Can you provide more code from your pipeline? What you seem to be doing is calling a template which has nothing to do with a task.

Answer (score 3):

The *retryCountOnTaskFailure* feature is applied to individual *tasks* within a pipeline. Templates aren't tasks, they act more like an *include* that expands the contents of the template into your pipeline.

```
# pipeline.yml

trigger: none

parameters:

- name: isTestRelease
  type: boolean
  default: false

- name: deploymentTarget
  type: string
  default: DEV
  values:
  - DEV
  - QA
  - UAT
  - PROD

- name: component
  type: string
  default: 'x'

stages:
- template: my-template.yml
  parameters:
    Test: ${{ parameters.isTestRelease }}
    Environment: ${{ parameters.deploymentTarget }}
    Component: ${{ parameters.component }}
```

And within the template, you'd want to add the retry logic to specific tasks:

```
# my-template.yml

parameters:
- name: isTestRelease
  type: boolean

- name: component
  type: string


stages:
- stage: Test
  jobs:
  - job: 1
    steps:
    - task: ...
    - task: ...

    - task: ...
      retryCountOnFailure: 2

    - task: ...
```

Comment: Is it possible call template inside the task ?

Comment: You can create templates for Stages, Jobs or Steps. So if you want to bundle multiple tasks together and parameterize them, you can use a [step template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-template?view=azure-pipelines)

Answer (score 0):

It's also located under "Control Options" when the "Command Line" task is added:
[image]